# What is the best practice for modeling Java classes with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a question about what would be the best practice for modeling my Java classes and how they should be related in the database. I'm using **Spring-Boot** and **Spring-Data** in the project

I have the situation containing professional Administrative, Professional Financial and Professional Developer. Each of them have specific characteristics.

So, I created a Professional class with the attibutos that are common to all employees:

**Professional Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Professional")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Professional {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String age;

    ... getters e setters
}
```

The other classes, extend from the professional class:

**Administrative Class**

```
@Entity
public class Administrative extends Professional {
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;

    ... getters e setters
}
```

**Financial Class**

```
@Entity
public class Financial extends Professional {
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;

    ... getters e setters
}
```

**Developer Class**

```
@Entity
public class Developer extends Professional {
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;

    ... getters e setters
}
```

Is this the most appropriate way to handle this scenario? Should I use Class Composition instead of Inheritance? Could you please share examples?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance makes more sense here. As an example, composition makes sense where an entity *has* another entity, e.g.

```
class Adult extends Person {
    private List<Animal> pets; // person HAS pets (with are another class)
    private ID identityCard; // person HAS an identity card
}
```

It wouldn't make sense here for a Person to extend either of `Animal` or `ID` because they aren't a subset of either. However, they are a child of the `Person` class so it makes sense to inherit.

In your case inheritance makes sense because your child classes *are* a subset of the Professional. You wouldn't say that a Developer *has* a Professional, but they *are a* Professional.

Comment: Thank you for your help Matt.